# s3distcp hangs after showing 100%

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr

In order to try to work around [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769431/performance-tuning-for-amazon-emr-hive-processing-large-number-of-files-in-s3) with Amazon EMR, I'm trying to use `s3distcp` to copy files over from S3 to my EMR cluster for local processing. As a first test, i'm copying over one day's data, 2160 files, from a single directory, using the `--groupBy` option to collapse them into one (or a few) files.

The job seems to run just fine, showing me the map/reduce progressing to 100%, but at this point the process hangs and never comes back. How can I figure out what's going on?

Source files are GZipped text files stored in S3, each one about 30kb. This is a vanilla Amazon EMR cluster, and I'm running s3distcp from the shell of the master node.

```
hadoop@ip-xxx:~$ hadoop jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar --src s3n://xxx/click/20140520 --dest hdfs:////data/click/20140520 --groupBy ".*(20140520).*" --outputCodec lzo
14/05/21 20:06:32 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Running with args: [Ljava.lang.String;@26f3bbad
14/05/21 20:06:35 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Using output path 'hdfs:/tmp/9f423c59-ec3a-465e-8632-ae449d45411a/output'
14/05/21 20:06:35 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone result: us-west-2b
14/05/21 20:06:35 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Created AmazonS3Client with conf KeyId AKIAJ5KT6QSV666K6KHA
14/05/21 20:06:37 INFO s3distcp.FileInfoListing: Opening new file: hdfs:/tmp/9f423c59-ec3a-465e-8632-ae449d45411a/files/1
14/05/21 20:06:38 INFO s3distcp.S3DistCp: Created 1 files to copy 2160 files
14/05/21 20:06:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of map tasks: null
14/05/21 20:06:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting default number of map tasks based on cluster size to : 72
14/05/21 20:06:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Default number of reduce tasks: 3
14/05/21 20:06:39 INFO security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping: add hadoop to shell userGroupsCache
14/05/21 20:06:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Setting group to hadoop
14/05/21 20:06:39 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/05/21 20:06:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201405211343_0031
14/05/21 20:06:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:06:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 1% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:06:56 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 4% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:06:59 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 36% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:07:00 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 44% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:07:02 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 54% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:07:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 86% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:07:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 94% reduce 0%
14/05/21 20:07:08 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 10%
14/05/21 20:07:11 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 19%
14/05/21 20:07:14 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 27%
14/05/21 20:07:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 29%
14/05/21 20:07:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
[hangs here]
```

The job shows as:

```
hadoop@xxx:~$ hadoop job -list
1 job currently running
JobId   State   StartTime       UserName        Priority        SchedulingInfo
job_201405211343_0031   1       1400702799339   hadoop  NORMAL  NA
```

and there's nothing in the destination HDFS directory:

```
hadoop@xxx:~$ hadoop dfs -ls /data/click/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure it never goes back, or it just does the first bucket quickly and then takes for ever for the rest? This is what I notice.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop@ip-xxx:~$ hadoop jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar --src s3n://xxx/click/20140520**/** --dest hdfs:////data/click/20140520**/** --groupBy ".*(20140520).*" --outputCodec lzo

I faced a similar problem. All I need was place a extra slash at the end of the directories. And consequently, it completed and with stats showing, prev it hung at 100%

Comment: does --outputCodec lzo provides indexed lzo compression (that can be divided into splits while running a hadoop job)?

Answer (score 0):

use s3:// instead of s3n.

hadoop jar /home/hadoop/lib/emr-s3distcp-1.0.jar --src s3://xxx/click/20140520 --dest hdfs:////data/click/20140520 --groupBy ".*(20140520).*" --outputCodec lzo